# Spotlight fails to load after Time Machine restore - crashes continuously

Tags: macos, time-machine, spotlight, crash, launchd

Problem description:
After having made the mistake of running a Unix command that altered more files than I intended and possibly damaged the file system, I decided to restore to a previous state with Time Machine.

Evidently, something was corrupted with the latest backup, since the system said it couldn’t restore every time I tried to use it. But I succeeded with the second newest backup.

Since the restoration, the Spotlight icon has disappeared from the corner of the menu bar, and cannot be activated with keyboard shortcuts. The same problem exists whether I start in safe mode or from a fresh account.

The .app file still exists in CoreServices, and indexing appears to continue, as I am able to conduct searches through finder windows. I have tried emptying all the caches, restarting SystemUIServer and the menubar itself.

I have never, to my knowledge, instructed an application or the computer to hide Spotlight from the menubar. And though I doubt this is the issue, it is interesting that when I select in Onyx the option to hide it, and then deselect it, there’s a short little flash in the corner where the icon should be as if it tries to start for a moment but for whatever reason crashes.

**It appears from the console that every second it is trying to load when this happens:**

> file:///Users/SRF/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-163022_MacBookPro.crash
>
> 2/11/15 4:30:46.173 PM    com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.Spotlight[1951]) Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
>
> 2/11/15 4:30:46.173 PM    com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.Spotlight) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
>
> 2/11/15 4:30:46.174 PM    ReportCrash[1919]   Saved crash report for Spotlight[1951] version ??? to /Users/SRF/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-163046_MacBookPro.crash
>
> 2/11/15 4:30:46.175 PM    ReportCrash[1919]   Removing excessive log:

**And then from the CrashReport:**

> Application Specific Information:
>   dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
>
> Dyld Error Message:
>   Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ParsecUI.framework/Versions/A/ParsecUI
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight
>     Reason: image not found

**Any comments, advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!**

> EtreCheck version: 2.1.8 (121)
>   Report generated February 11, 2015 at 4:54:44 PM EST
>   Download EtreCheck from http://etresoft.com/etrecheck
>
> Hardware Information: ℹ️
>       MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) (Technical Specifications)
>       MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro11,3
>       1 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU: 4-core
>       16 GB RAM Not upgradeable
>           BANK 0/DIMM0
>               8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
>           BANK 1/DIMM0
>               8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
>       Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
>       Wireless:  en0: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
>       Battery Health: Normal - Cycle count 111
>
> Video Information: ℹ️
>       Intel Iris Pro
>       NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M - VRAM: 2048 MB
>           Color LCD spdisplays_2880x1800Retina
>
> System Software: ℹ️
>       OS X 10.10.2 (14C109) - Time since boot: 0:36:32
>
> Disk Information: ℹ️
>       APPLE SSD SM1024F disk0 : (1 TB)
>           EFI (disk0s1)  : 210 MB 
>           Recovery HD (disk0s3)   [Recovery]: 650 MB 
>           Macintosh HD (disk1) / : 999.33 GB (497.93 GB free)
>               Core Storage: disk0s2 999.70 GB Online
>
> USB Information: ℹ️
>       Apple Internal Memory Card Reader 
>       Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
>           Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
>       Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
>       Kingston DT 101 G2 15.51 GB
>           DiskWarrior Recovery (disk2s1) /Volumes/DiskWarrior Recovery : 15.51 GB (14.24 GB free)
>
> Thunderbolt Information: ℹ️
>       Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus
>
> Configuration files: ℹ️
>       /etc/sysctl.conf - Exists
>
> Gatekeeper: ℹ️
>       Anywhere
>
> Kernel Extensions: ℹ️
>           /Applications/DiskWarrior.app
>       [not loaded]    com.alsoft.Preview (5 - SDK 10.5) [Click for support]

```
    /Applications/VMware Fusion.app
[not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmci (90.6.3) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmioplug.14.1.3 (14.1.3) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmnet (0231.47.74) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmx86 (0231.47.74) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vsockets (90.6.0) [Click for support]

    /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
[loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (4.3.20) [Click for support]
[loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (4.3.20) [Click for support]
[loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (4.3.20) [Click for support]
[loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (4.3.20) [Click for support]

    /Library/Extensions
[not loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.iokit.driver (10.3.4 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.iokit.framebufferdriver (10.3.4 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.multibridge.iokit.driver (10.3.4 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.driver.BlackmagicIO (10.3.4 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.driver.BlackmagicUsbIO (10.3.4 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]

    /Library/Extensions/DeckLink_Driver.kext/Contents/PlugIns
[not loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.firmware (10.3.4 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]

    /System/Library/Extensions
[not loaded]    com.makemkv.kext.daspi (1) [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.nvidia.CUDA (1.1.0) [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.plantronics.driver.PlantronicsDriverShield (4.3 - SDK 10.8) [Click for support]
```

> Problem System Launch Agents: ℹ️
>       [failed]    com.apple.security.keychain-circle-notification.plist [Click for details]
>       [failed]    com.apple.Spotlight.plist [Click for details]
>
> Launch Agents: ℹ️
>       [not loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusagent.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusnotifications.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.blackmagic-design.DesktopVideoFirmwareUpdater.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.brother.LOGINserver.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.LogOut.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.PurgeInactiveMemory.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.Restart.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.ShutDown.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.Sleep.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.maintain.SystemEvents.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.nvidia.CUDASoftwareUpdate.plist [Click for support]
>       [unknown]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.plantronics.Spokes.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    org.gpgtools.gpgmail.enable-bundles.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist [Click for support]
>
> Launch Daemons: ℹ️
>       [not loaded]    com.adobe.adobeupdatedaemon.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.backblaze.bzserv.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusdaemon.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.XPCService.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.blackmagic-design.DesktopVideoHelper.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.blackmagic-design.streaming.BMDStreamingServer.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.bresink.system.privilegedhelper-tts.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.creativebe.MainMenuHelper.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.edb.launchd.postgresql-8.4.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.informer.mac.daemon.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.macromates.auth_server.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.CocktailScheduler.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.maintain.HideSpotlightMenuBarIcon.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.nvidia.cuda.launcher.plist [Click for support]
>       [unknown]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.oracle.java.JavaUpdateHelper.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.soma-zone.LaunchControl.Helper.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.sonos.smbbump.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.startup.plist [Click for support]
>
> User Launch Agents: ℹ️
>       [not loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.adobe.ARM.[...].plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.backblaze.bzbmenu.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.ctmdev.foxtrot.prostarter.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    com.informer.mac.client.plist [Click for support]
>       [loaded]    com.leadertech.PowerRegister.SEA1.5dbf409444be57eee48085fc658738f0.plist [Click for support]
>       [running]    com.pia.pia_manager.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist [Click for support]
>       [not loaded]    SOS.OnlineBackup.LaunchAgent.plist [Click for support]
>
> User Login Items: ℹ️
>       Citations    Application  (/Applications/Papers.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Citations.app)
>       iTunesHelper    Application  (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app)
>       Dropbox    Application Hidden (/Applications/Dropbox.app)
>       Alfred 2    Application  (/Applications/Alfred 2.app)
>       TextExpander    Application  (/Users/[redacted]/.Trash/TextExpander.app)
>       HazelHelper    Application  (/Users/[redacted]/Library/PreferencePanes/Hazel.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/HazelHelper.app)
>       DiskWarriorDaemonStarter    Application  (/Applications/DiskWarrior.app/Contents/Helpers/DiskWarriorStarter.app)
>
> Internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
>       AdobeAAMDetect: Version: AdobeAAMDetect 2.0.0.0 - SDK 10.7 [Click for support]
>       FlashPlayer-10.6: Version: 16.0.0.305 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
>       QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
>       Flash Player: Version: 16.0.0.305 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
>       Default Browser: Version: 600 - SDK 10.10
>       SharePointBrowserPlugin: Version: 14.4.7 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
>       Mathematica: Version: 9.0.1.4092152 [Click for support]
>       JavaAppletPlugin: Version: Unknown Check version
>
> User internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
>       Google Earth Web Plug-in: Version: 7.1 [Click for support]
>
> Safari Extensions: ℹ️
>       JavaScript Blocker
>       Open in Papers
>       Blur (Formerly DoNotTrackMe)
>       Disconnect
>       Zotero Connector
>       DuckDuckGo
>       1Password
>       Clip to DEVONthink
>       Adblock Plus
>
> 3rd Party Preference Panes: ℹ️
>       Backblaze Backup  [Click for support]
>       Blackmagic Desktop Video  [Click for support]
>       CleanApp Logging Service  [Click for support]
>       CUDA Preferences  [Click for support]
>       Default Folder X  [Click for support]
>       Flash Player  [Click for support]
>       FUSE for OS X (OSXFUSE)  [Click for support]
>       Hazel  [Click for support]
>       Perian  [Click for support]
>
> Time Machine: ℹ️
>       Mobile backups: OFF
>       Auto backup: NO - Auto backup turned off
>       Volumes being backed up:
>       Destinations:
>           Seagate [Local] 
>           Total size: 999.86 GB 
>           Total number of backups: 6 
>           Oldest backup: 2015-02-02 07:49:49 +0000 
>           Last backup: 2015-02-07 07:22:10 +0000 
>           Size of backup disk: Excellent
>               Backup size 999.86 GB > (Disk size 0 B X 3)
>
> Top Processes by CPU: ℹ️
>           51%    Console
>            7%    WindowServer
>            3%    mds
>            1%    pia_tray
>            1%    hidd
>
> Top Processes by Memory: ℹ️
>       653 MB    Finder
>       618 MB    Safari
>       515 MB    Console
>       210 MB    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
>       172 MB    WindowServer
>
> Virtual Memory Information: ℹ️
>       10.18 GB    Free RAM
>       4.81 GB    Active RAM
>       667 MB    Inactive RAM
>       1.51 GB    Wired RAM
>       1.87 GB    Page-ins
>       0 B    Page-outs
>
> Diagnostics Information: ℹ️
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:36 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165436_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:34 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165434_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:33 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165433_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:31 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165431_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:28 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165428_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:26 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165426_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:23 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165423_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:21 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165421_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:18 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165418_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:15 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165415_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 08:16:18 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/DiskWarrior_2015-02-11-081618_[redacted].cpu_resource.diag [Click for details]
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:31:16 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-073116_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:30:20 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-073020_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:24:14 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072414_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:23:43 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072343_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:23:32 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072332_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:23:12 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072312_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:23:02 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072302_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:22:31 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072231_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:22:20 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072220_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:22:00 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072200_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:21:39 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072139_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:21:08 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072108_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:20:58 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072058_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 05:56:00 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-055600_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:32 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165432_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:30 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165430_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:29 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165429_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:24 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165424_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:22 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165422_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:19 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165419_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:16 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165416_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:14 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165414_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:31:20 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/garcon_2015-02-11-163120_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:17:59 PM    Self test - passed
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:30:44 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-073044_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:30:44 AM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/*2015-02-11-073044*[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:28:25 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-072825_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:24:03 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072403_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:23:53 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072353_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:23:22 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072322_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:22:41 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072241_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:22:10 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072210_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:21:49 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072149_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:21:29 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072129_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:21:18 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072118_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 05:37:39 AM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/CleanApp_2015-02-11-053739_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:25 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165425_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 04:54:17 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-02-11-165417_[redacted].crash
>       Feb 11, 2015, 07:22:51 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/postgres_2015-02-11-072251_[redacted].crash

Answer (score 1):

At this point I see two options for a potential fix.
If in a new admin user spotlight is functional, then I would remove .plist files from your user library preferences.
If it is not functional, then you will need to reinstall Yosemite from the recovery partition due to the application being corrupt.